# local notification automatic update

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have an Event management solution with web and mobile app (for both android and ios). 
I am using Phonegap 2.7 for mobile app. 
In my mobile app, I'm just displaying the data that is created and updated using web solution. I have a list of "Tasks" and "On-Site Tasks" in the mobile app with Date and Time and have scheduled local notifications for all the items using Phonegap's local notification plugin. The notifications are working as expected and I am recieving them on time.

But when the data is updated using web solution I have to reschedule the local notification on device and for this I have to launch the app every time I want to update the previously scheduled notifications.

My question is, Is there a way to update the local notifications whenever the data is updated on web solution without launching the app ??
I want the local notifications to be updated automatically when the data is updated from web solution.

Comment: Please comment while down voting. Atleast I should know the reason

Comment: @user3003959 I don't know why exactly someone downvoted you, but I'm sure you can find the answer here: [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), IMHO It would be because you didn't show any attempt to solve this on your own.

Comment: I don't know the answer, that's why I have posted it here. If its an obvious answer, maybe Im not aware of it..

Comment: @stackoverflow: just a suggestion.. please make it a compulsion to add a comment if someone is down voting something.

Comment: I agree on that comments should be mandatory while downvoting, but I believe there were some discussion about this on meta. Anyway people usually require others to show their efforst when they ask questions.

Comment: Can you please post the link of that discussion. It would be of great help. Thanks !!!

Comment: So far this is the best discussion about this matter: [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes), however you can find more topics about downvoting in meta ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS dev here, I don't know Phonegap nor do I know Android. But in general for iOS:

You need to use push notifications instead. The purpose of local notifications is to maintain them completely client-side. If the notification depends on server-side state, and you do not want to launch the app to update notifications, you need to dispatch the notifications using push.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

Comment: Thanks for the answer nevyn.. I know about push notifications.. But I want something like Outlook. e.g. when we update any event using a desktop or laptop in our outlook calendar, it automatically gets added to my android/apple device calendar